# Using XPath Contains

Tags: xpath

I am trying to scrape price data off various websites. All is working fine except for one site where the XPath for the price is unique for each product page e.g.
Page A - `//*[@id="price-including-tax-2940"]`
Page B - `//*[@id="price-including-tax-1456"]`
i.e. they all have a unique number as part of the query string.

This is an example of one of the pages in question http://thepowersite.co.uk/honda-gx200-powered-gear-driven-pump-pressure-washer-b2565hag

To save me finding the unique XPath for price on each page, I am trying to modify the Xpath query to remove the unique number. I've tried various things along these lines, `//*[id=[contains(.,'price-including')]]` but my lack of understanding of XPath is letting me down.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems you want

```
//*[contains(@id,'price-including')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `contains` function operates on the value of the `id` attribute by writing your query like this:

```
//*[contains(@id, "price-including")]
```